# How can i define a class to deserialze binary file

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I would like to know how can i define a class for a binary file which contains objects with float array of size 19.

please see the attached picture of how data looks like in Hex Editor Neo. when displayed as float

[image]

i have tried following but no luck. please tell what i am doing wrong here.

```
  [ProtoContract]
public class ChannelData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<float> array = new List<float>(19);
}

using (var file = File.OpenRead("0.cnl"))
{
  ChannelData newchannel = Serializer.Deserialize<ChannelData>(file);
}
```

I am using protobuff for deserialize. Thankyou!

that binary file is not serialized using any binary serializer its raw file.
so i think it can not be deserialize using any deserializer? may be need to do with BitConverter but have no idea..

Comment: shouldn't it be `[ProtoMember(0)]`?

Comment: oh may bad actually i just found thats binary file is not serialized using any binary serializer it has no attributes. so i think it can not be deserialize using any deserializer? may be need to do with BitConverter but have no idea...:(

Comment: as far as my understanding of protocol buffers goes I understood that no attributes are written to the file and that the serializer/deserializer has to know the format / the bitconverter is only for single datatype serialization and deserialization.. you need to parse multiple

Comment: oh okay. i am trying to do this first time no experience in protobuf but gone through some similar questions on stackoverflow and trying. let me try that with by setting protomember(0).

Comment: You dont really need the class, you can serialize the `List<float>` directly

Comment: binary file have n packets. each packet is called Channel and each Channel Have 19 Floating values . each file can contains upto 1000 Channel Packets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load floats to the list, then split it to Channels, like

```
public static unsafe List<float> LoadToList(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var list = new List<float>();
        var step = sizeof (float);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += step)
        {
            fixed (byte* pbyte = &bytes[i])
            {
                list.Add(*((float*)pbyte));
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```